# Is it possible to add the video duration to JWPlayer using the JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I have a bunch of files on my server that get encoded in realtime when JWPlayer requests it. Since it's a non-seekable video, JWPlayer does not show the duration. I have an API on my server that can return the duration of the original video. So is it possible to add this duration info to JWPlayer using JavaScript?

This is what I tried to do:

> ```
> <div id="vid">Loading...</div> <script type="text/javascript">
>
> jwplayer("vid").setup({
>     file: "/watch?id=300",
>     type: 'flv',
>     duration: "3600"
> });
> ```

If this is not possible, is there an alternate flash/html5 player that provides this capability?

Comment: This is for JW6. I do not see any option under onMeta() to add the duration.

Comment: Yes, we don't have a duration variable, per say, in JW6, any more.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like:

```
jwplayer("vid").setup({
    file: "/watch?id=300",
    type: 'flv',
    onReady: function() {
       setText("durationText", "duration = " + 3600); //3600 is your duration
       slider.enable();
    }
});
```